# React Native vertical scroll interpolation not working

Tags: react-native

So I am having some issues figuring out what I thought to be a simple animation ...

https://snack.expo.io/H1ssxISrf

Basically, if you replace `topBarOpacity` from `interpolate` to `1` you should see the actual bar on top ... I just want that small background view to appear ( fade in / out depending on the scroll position ).

While I can see the `Animated.Event` trigger upon scrolling, I just can't get the opacity to work as expected.

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after for, but does this hit the target at all: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/interpolating-opacity

The idea is to take offset and then set it to state and after that access the opacity controlling:

```
onScroll={({ nativeEvent }) => {
  this.setState({
    scrollY: new Animated.Value(nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)
  }, this.changeOpacity);
}}
```

There's a "bug" in code since I moved also the opacity as a state property and now it triggers render twice per scroll (causing issues on perf). But maybe you have energy - after the original problem is hopefully solved - to optimise your code?

Comment: I am not sure if I can fix the issue as I'm quite new to all this animation stuff, but I'll surely give it a try. It works as intended. Just wanted a top background under the statusBar while scrolling downwards in the app :) Any suggestions for the render issue ? How should I approach this